# Show the euro simbol in a shiny R application

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a shiny R application. I have some troubles to show euro symbol (and return it) in a radio button. I've tried different version of code:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(
ui= navbarPage(title = 'shoe euro',
radioButtons('var', 'var',  
c("INCOME_MGL",
"INCOME_MGL€",
"INCOME_MGL&euro;",
"INCOME_MGL&#8364;",
"INCOME_MGL\u20ac")     
                        )),
 server=function(input, output, session) {
  }))
```

But the "€" doesn't appear in the web page. Moreover if I select the second option the page returns an error:

```
"Error in fromJSON(content, handler, default.size, depth, allowComments,  : 
  invalid JSON input"
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine on my device. What version of R, shiny etc are you running?

Comment: I got the same error.  I am running RStudio 0.98.1087, R 3.1.2, shiny 0.11.1, all on a Windows 7 Professional (64 Bit) machine.  The error occurred in the built in RStudio browser and in Chrome 41.0.2272.101 m.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in the class `shiny-options-group` in the `div` function.  The way this class works appears to convert `&` to `&amp;`, preventing the browser from converting `&#8364;` into `€` because it first changes it into `&amp;#8364;`.   Try the following as your ui.R to see it happen.

```
library(shiny)
options = as.list(c("a","b",HTML("&#8364;"),"€"))
shinyUI(fluidPage("test",fluidRow(div(class = "shiny-options-group", options))))
```

The reason this is happening in your radio button widget is that `radioButtons` calls `generateOptions` to create the list of options, and `generateOptions` returns `div(class = "shiny-options-group", options)`, where `options` is derived from a manipulation of the `choices` parameter in the `radioButtons` function.  Here is what you could do:

1. Get the code for `generateOptions` [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/R/bootstrap.R) (line 653).
2. Define the new function `generateOptions2` using the exact same code as `generateOptions`, but change the class parameter at the end.
3. Get the code for `radioButtons` by running `shiny::radioButtons`
4. Define a new function `radioButtons2` and in it replace the `generateOptions` with `generateOptions2`.
5. Set the environment for both new functions to `shiny` by running something like `environment(radioButtons2) <- environment(radioButtons)`
6. Use `radioButtons2` in your code instead of `radioButtons`

The only thing I don't know is what to change the class parameter to in `generateOptions2`.  I don't know much about `div` classes.

## Update

I may have spoken too soon.  It looks like the problem goes far deeper.  The `div` function calls `tags$div`, which calls `tag` with the first argument set to `"div"`.  `tag` then calls the base function `structure` with the parameter `class = "shiny.tag"`.  `structure` then calls the primitive function `attributes` with the parameter `class = "shiny.tag"`.  `attributes` with this parameter then converts `&` in to `&amp;`.  Therefore, it looks like there is no way to use the `div` function and get back the euro symbol.  I tried replacing `div` in `generateOptions2` with `HTML`, but that returned a bunch of garbage when I ran the app.  You'd have to change the behavior of `class = "shiny.tag"`, but that could have far-reaching unpredictable effects.

## Update 2

Figured it out!  The trick is to use `gsub` to replace every `&amp;` with just `&` before it is returned from `generateOptions2`.  I put a functioning version of what you posted [on github](https://github.com/debarros/EuroSymbol).  It requires loading the two functions I mentioned earlier, which (in my repository) are stored in a file called `functions.R`.  The important line in `generateOptions2` is `gsub(pattern = "&amp;", replacement = "&", div(class = "shiny-options-group", options))`.